# How to resolve Boolean value error in linear regression model in python?

Tags: python, linear-regression

I am trying to run a fama-macbeth regression in a python. As afirst step I am running the time series for every asset in my portfolio but I am unable to run it because I am getting an error:
'ValueError: Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only'

I am relatively new to python and have heavily relied on this forum to help me out. I hope it you can help me with this issue. 
Please let me know how I can resolve this. I will be very grateful to you!

I assume this line is producing the error. Cause when I run the function without the for loop, it works perfectly.

```
for i in range(cols):
    df_beta = RegressionRoll(df=data_set, subset = 0, dependent = data_set.iloc[:,i], independent = data_set.iloc[:,30:], const = True, parameters = 'beta',
                                     win = 12)
```

The dimension of my matrix is 108x35, 30 stocks and 5 factors over 108 points. Hence I want to run a regression for every stock against the 4 factors and store the result of the coeffs in a dataframe. Sample dataframe:

```
Date        BAS GY  AI FP   SGL GY  LNA GY  AKZA NA  Market Factor
1/29/2010   -5.28%  -7.55%  -1.23%  -5.82%  -7.09%    -5.82%
2/26/2010   0.04%   13.04%  -1.84%  4.06%   -14.62%   -14.62% 
3/31/2010   10.75%  1.32%   7.33%   6.61%   12.21%    12.21%
```

The following is the entire code:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import variance_inflation_factor


data_set = pd.read_excel(r'C:\XXX\Research Project\Data\Regression.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Fama Macbeth')
data_set.set_index(data_set['Date'], inplace=True) 
data_set.drop('Date', axis=1, inplace=True)

X = data_set.iloc[:,30:]
y = data_set.iloc[:,:30]

def RegressionRoll(df, subset, dependent, independent, const, win, parameters):

    # Data subset
    if subset != 0:
        df = df.tail(subset)
    else:
        df = df

    # Loopinfo
    end = df.shape[0]
    win = win
    rng = np.arange(start = win, stop = end, step = 1)

    # Subset and store dataframes
    frames = {}
    n = 1

    for i in rng:
        df_temp = df.iloc[:i].tail(win)
        newname = 'df' + str(n)
        frames.update({newname: df_temp})
        n += 1

    # Analysis on subsets
    df_results = pd.DataFrame()
    for frame in frames:
        #print(frames[frame])

        # Rolling data frames
        dfr = frames[frame]
        y = dependent
        x = independent

        if const == True:
            x = sm.add_constant(dfr[x])
            model = sm.OLS(dfr[y], x).fit()
        else:
            model = sm.OLS(dfr[y], dfr[x]).fit()

        if parameters == 'beta':
            theParams = model.params[0:]
            coefs = theParams.to_frame()
            df_temp = pd.DataFrame(coefs.T)
            indx = dfr.tail(1).index[-1]
            df_temp['Date'] = indx
            df_temp = df_temp.set_index(['Date'])
            df_results = pd.concat([df_results, df_temp], axis = 0)

        if parameters == 'R2':
            theParams = model.rsquared
            df_temp = pd.DataFrame([theParams])
            indx = dfr.tail(1).index[-1]
            df_temp['Date'] = indx
            df_temp = df_temp.set_index(['Date'])
            df_temp.columns = [', '.join(independent)]
            df_results = pd.concat([df_results, df_temp], axis = 0)

    return(df_results)

cols = len(y.columns)

for i in range(cols):
    df_beta = RegressionRoll(df=data_set, subset = 0, dependent = data_set.iloc[:,i], independent = data_set.iloc[:,30:], const = True, parameters = 'beta',
                                     win = 12)
```

ValueError: Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only

Comment: Please add which line produces the error.

Comment: And also a sample of your dataframe.